# Porting bit modification code from C to Java

Tags: java, c, bit, translate, unsigned

I am doing a pokerHand evaluator in Java, for what I m using one implemented in C (http://www.suffecool.net/poker/evaluator.html). I have "translated" the code and it works pretty well and fast. Now I want to add some HashTables to make it faster, and it looks pretty simple, as it is explained here: http://www.paulsenzee.com/2006/06/some-perfect-hash.html
But it ends up that the code doesn't work, and I ve realized that is in the following function:

```
unsigned find_fast(unsigned u)
{
    unsigned a, b, r;
    u += 0xe91aaa35;
    u ^= u >> 16;
    u += u << 8;
    u ^= u >> 4;
    b  = (u >> 8) & 0x1ff;
    a  = (u + (u << 2)) >> 19;
    r  = a ^ hash_adjust[b];
    return r;
}
```

I think "unsigned" without anything else in C is an integer, but in java this function doesnt generate the same as in C, and r sometimes is a negative value, which does not make sense. As far as I know there is nothing like the unsigned operator in Java, and I think is causes problem understanding some representations as negative numbers.
Could someone help me to translate that code into Java?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that stack overflow is not a code translation service, post the java code you tried, what it was ment to do and what went wrong

Comment: Yes sorry, I didnt want you to translate it, I guess that I didnt explain me well. I didnt try anything strange in Java, basically because I didnt know about unsigned variables or how to simulate them in that language, I just tried replacing unsigned for int, and googled when it didnt work. Anyway, csoroiu's answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing `unsigned` to `int` and `>>` shift operator to java's `>>>` unsigned shift operator.

this should be valid if your `unsigned` type is 32 bits long.

in java all number primitives are signed, but using the hint, your method should work similar to `C` version.